# how to move image vertically with css

Tags: html, css, mousehover

i m working with wordpress and wooslider. My problem is that i want to pan an thumbnail image on mouse hover like this: [Sample Site](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/44427.html)

This is the output I achieved from wooslider however i want the effect to be like the one mentioned above: [Wooslider effect](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html)

The css has the following lines, however Im finding it tough to figure out what edits to make in order to achieve the above effect

```
.wooslider-control-thumbs img:hover {opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: What effect actually are you looking for? Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: i want the effect shown on this site on thumbnails:
<a href="http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/44427.html">sample site</a>

Comment: @Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui : what if i m a newby to these things sir

Comment: If what you want is the effect of popping up the selected option, just play with the element height and bottom position, as the other site is doing it.

Comment: However you will have to play around with properties given to other elements as well, for example the image your trying to manipulate in held in an li and in an ol, the ol has its overflow set to hidden, you will have to change these properties as well

Comment: @TDsouza : i have tried all things said by u and mishik but its working opposite as down and up and i want it up and down can u tell me why?

Comment: have you changed the properties of `.wooslider-control-thumbs img {opacity: 1;` as well??? mashik's basic logic was to add a higher `margin-top` to `img` and a lesser `margin-top` to `img:hover`, if you changed both it should work, I tried it and it did...

Comment: i have removed the opacity from both img and img hover but still not working..:(

Comment: add the following lines to `.flex-control-thumbs img` `transition-property` `bottom` `transition-duration` to `1s` `position` to `relative` and `bottom` to `0px. Then add the following lines to `.flex-control-thumbs img:hover` `bottom` `30px` also create a new rule for ol with the following lines `height` `144px` and `overflow` `visible`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, you are looking for CSS transitions:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mishik/cKeQ2/)

Example:

HTML:

```
<img src="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
```

CSS:

```
img {
    margin: 40px;
}

img:hover {
    margin-top: 20px;
    transition: margin 1s;
}
```

Comment: thats what i exactly looking for.thanks a ton sir but i just want to ask one thing that why its moving downwards

Comment: it's moving downward because u have applied a `margin-top` which means space the element will leave from the top, change it to `margin-bottom` to achieve the effect your looking for.

Comment: When you hover - it moves up, when not - down. To make moving down smoother add "transition" to `img` too: http://jsfiddle.net/mishik/cKeQ2/1/

Answer (score 2):

I create this for You [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/RQ62f/51/)

html:

```
<ul>
<li><div>1</div></li>
<li><div>2</div></li>
<li><div>3</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
transition-duration: 0s;
width: 800%;
display: table;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
transform: none !important;
width: 100% !important;
}
ul li
{
float: left;
width: 160px;
background-color:gray;
border-right: 1px solid white;
height: 200px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}
div
{
padding-top: 77px;
height: 100px;
background-color: gold;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
div:hover
{
height:123px;
}
```

Comment: thnks for ur help but i cant change much the css of plugin

Comment: did You mean wooslider Plugin

Comment: yes exactly as i mentioned in my question

Comment: why its easy you just need to deal with "img" in slider like div in my example 
and same "Li" and "ul" see what i write in css and try to use it in the slider you will see the chages and let me know if its not work :)